# how to add metafield in search shopify?

Tags: shopify

[Custom search filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVMOm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVMOm.png)

Specifically, I want to be able to customize the search algorithm to consider the data within these metafields when a customer uses the search bar. For example, if I have a product with a metafield called "Brand," I'd like the search to not only consider the product's title, but also this "Brand" metafield when displaying relevant results.

I've tried researching this topic, but I couldn't find a comprehensive guide or up-to-date information on how to achieve this. Has anyone successfully implemented metafields in the Shopify search functionality? How can I modify the default search behavior to include metafields in the search process and ensure the search results are accurate and relevant?

Any insights, code examples, or step-by-step instructions on how to implement this feature would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it something like this

```
{% comment %}
  This Liquid code iterates through products in a collection
  and checks if any of their metafields contain a specified search term.
{% endcomment %}

{% assign search = "your_search_term" %}

{% for product in collections.all.products %}
  {% assign metafields = product.metafields %}
  
  {% comment %}
    Iterate through each metafield of the current product.
  {% endcomment %}
  {% for metafield in metafields %}
    {% comment %}
      Check if the metafield value contains the search term.
    {% endcomment %}
    {% if metafield.value contains search %}
      <a href="{{ product.url }}">{{ product.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

if you need more dynamic or real-time search capabilities. However, it involves more complex development, including creating a custom app and handling the interaction between the front end and the back end. It's a good option if you need more advanced features that Liquid alone might not provide. The choice between the two approaches depends on your specific requirements and the level of customization you need for your search functionality.